# java 8 List<Pair<String, Integer>> to List<String>

Tags: java, java-8

There is a List>:

```
List<Pair<String, Integer>> list =new ArrayList<>();
```

Pair is `javafx.util.Pair` which has a key and a value.
and a

```
Integer tmp;
```

how should I get all String which `Pair.getValue() >=tmp`  by java 8 stream?

Comment: What is a `Pair`? Are you using `org.apache.commons.lang3.tuple.Pair`?

Comment: This can't be answered without knowing how to access the `Integer` member of `Pair`.

Comment: Pair is javafx.util.Pair; @davioooh

Answer (score 5):

Something like this, haven't compiled it since I can't tell what a `Pair` is; but assuming it has two parts `left` and `right` and there are getters for it.

```
list.filter(p -> p.getRight() >= tmp)
    .map(Pair::getLeft)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: it doesn't work. The Error message is that:
Incompatible types. Required List<Pair<String, Integer>> but 'collect' was inferred to R: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that String conforms to Pair<String, Integer> inference variable T has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: Pair<String, Integer> lower bounds: String

Comment: @linhos you have to show the exact things that you have tried

Answer (score 0):

```
list.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getValue() >= tmp)
    .map(pair -> pair.getKey())
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Where map can be changed to static method reference as Pair::getValue

Since this will return a stream and you most likely want to get back a List, you need to transform it to a list with .collect(Collection.asList())

Comment: `Collection.asList()`? Are you sure? `collect()` method takes in a `Collector` not a `Collection`